# Master Page and Existing Web Form

Tags: asp.net

I'm new here and this is my first question.

I am working with VS 2005 and I have built a web form, I have also built a master page (you might imagine what is my question now :) ), I am not able to assign that MP to my WebForm. The MasterPageFile property from my webform is disable (in grey) and I am not able to assing the MP.

I will need the assistance from you as soon as possible :(

Cheers,
JZ

Answer (score 0):

First create the master page, then create the Web form using the Add New Item (right-click in Solution Explorer, and select Add New Item). Be sure to check the "Select master page" check box:

[Tutorial 3: Master Pages and Site Navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581781.aspx)